# How to link existing local and remote branches in PhpStorm Git GUI?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm trying to replicate the `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/my-remote-branch` command using PhpStorm Git GUI but cannot find such an option anywhere. In SmartGit this option called `Set Tracked Branch...`.

I know that remote tracking will be set up automatically on pushing the whole branch from scratch. Also, it will be tracked on creating a new local branch from the remote one. However, I'm want to link two existing branches rather than create new ones.

I found some really old topics saying that there's no such functionality so I'm just wondering whether it's still so or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to set upstream via GUI.

There is a feature request, please vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170083

Comment: Thanks for the link. Hopefully, it will ever be implemented.